# Close ModalView on back button.(Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, navigation, modal-dialog

I am showing a ModalView(Navigation page) on button click.
Its working well. I want to close Modalview on Back button.
If you have any idea guide me.

My code as follows.
Button click event

```
 protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var navigation = new NavigationPage(new Settings());
        UIViewController navc = navigation.CreateViewController();
        navc.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
         this.PresentViewController(navc, true, null);
    }
```

Setting Form code

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Settings : ContentPage
{
    public Settings()
    {

        var backItem = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Text = "Back"
        };            
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(backItem);
        backItem .SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty, "BackClicked");
        backItem .Clicked += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
        {
            **// This code Not working**
            Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
        };
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be mixing iOS specific code with Forms code.  Is there a problem with the code you have?  An error or exception, or incorrect behavior?  Please be specific, we shouldn't have to guess what it's doing.

Comment: Error is not showing at runtime.
Modal view is showing properly. but close is not working.

I am using crossplatform. On button click i want to show modalview and on back button want to close the view.
Can you suggest any good way.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be mixing native iOS code with Xamarin.Forms code, as @Jason mentions in the comment. To open a modal view from XamForms, you can call `Navigation.PushModal()`:

```
protected async void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var navigation = new NavigationPage(new Settings());
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(navigation);
}
```

**Update** based on comment

```
public class MyTabbarPage : TabbarPage
{
    ...

    public void ButtonClicked()
    {
        var navigation = new NavigationPage(new Settings());
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(navigation);
    }
}


// Inside renderer

protected async void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (Element as MyTabbarPage).ButtonClicked();
}
```

Comment: I have created Custom render class for tabbar to add a Round button on center of tapbar. When user click the model want to display.

So when i use Navigation class in Tabbar render class, It showing error message as Navigation does not exist in current document.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a sub class in your XamForms project which has public method that you can call every time the button is clicked, that way you can handle the navigation in you XamForms code

Comment: Inside render code not worked.
So i used below code

                                                                                                
 Maintabpage obj =(Maintabpage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;
                obj.ButtonClicked();

Answer (score 0):

I did as below code to call XamForms class function an its worked.

```
  protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Maintabpage obj =(Maintabpage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;
                obj.ButtonClicked();
            }
```